# Using Google Picker to upload files to Google Drive and place in specific folder

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-picker

I am attempting to use Google Picker to upload files to a specific folder in Google Drive. Everything works fine when I am just uploading to the root folder, but even after specifying the parent folder as shown in my code below, the files still go to the root folder, not the folder I am specifying. I am certain the folderID is correct, as I am using the same ID elsewhere to create textiles in my GAE app, and place them in subfolders. My code is below:

```
    function createPicker() {
            // Create a view to search images.
            var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
            view.setMimeTypes('image/png,image/jpeg');

            // Use DocsUploadView to upload documents to Google Drive.
            var uploadView = new google.picker.DocsUploadView().setParent('THE Parent folder ID');

            var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
                addView(view).
                addView(uploadView).
                setAppId("pressomatic").
                setCallback(pickerCallback).
                build();
            picker.setVisible(true);
        }
```

Comment: I guess the parent only works for browsing, not uploads and that would appear to be a bug.

Comment: Ali, you may be interested in the following work-around I found elsewhere for another problem that also fixes my problem. This may have even been suggested by you, but I cannot find the original post. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11680890/1501783

Answer (score 4):

You have to add:

```
enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
```

In your case it becomes:

```
    var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED).
            addView(view).
            addView(uploadView).
            setAppId("pressomatic").
            setCallback(pickerCallback).
            build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug documented in the Picker API Forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-Picker-API/xaHcET7JYLw

You have to add:

```
.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
```

In your case it becomes:

```
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
        .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
        .addView(view)
        .addView(uploadView)
        .setAppId("pressomatic")
        .setCallback(pickerCallback)
        .build();
```

Hope this helps.